# Handle Socket.IO requests through Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io

My backend handles both API requests and Socket.IO requests perfectly in the development. In production, my backend still handles API requests perfectly but doesn't respond to Socket.IO requests.

It seems Socket.IO client connects to the backend with no problem as it gets `pong` with `undefined` data and the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Server: nginx/1.17.6
Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 08:50:51 GMT
Connection: upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: +XXXXxxXxxX/xxxxXXXxxxxx/Xx=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

**Update 1**

I tried connecting to the backend using [Echo Test](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html) and it successfully connected.

**Update 2**

Here are Socket.IO client logs:

```
socket.io-client:url parse https://staging.backend.xxx.us/dashboard
socket.io-client new io instance for https://staging.backend.xxx.us/dashboard
socket.io-client:socket emitting packet with ack id 0
socket.io-client:socket emitting packet with ack id 1
socket.io-client:socket emitting packet with ack id 2
socket.io-client:manager readyState closed
socket.io-client:manager opening https://staging.backend.xxx.us/dashboard
engine.io-client:socket creating transport "websocket"
engine.io-client:socket setting transport websocket
socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000
engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "open", data "{"sid":"fk3DbI3H-0qXRZEAAAAU","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}"
engine.io-client:socket socket open
socket.io-client:manager open
socket.io-client:manager cleanup
socket.io-client:socket transport is open - connecting
socket.io-client:manager writing packet {"type":0,"nsp":"/dashboard"}
socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":0,"nsp":"/dashboard"}
socket.io-parser encoded {"type":0,"nsp":"/dashboard"} as 0/dashboard,
engine.io-client:socket flushing 1 packets in socket
engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "message", data "0"
socket.io-parser decoded 0 as {"type":0,"nsp":"/"}
engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "message", data "4/dashboard,"invalid signature""
socket.io-parser decoded 4/dashboard,"invalid signature" as {"type":4,"nsp":"/dashboard","data":"invalid signature"}
engine.io-client:socket writing ping packet - expecting pong within 5000ms
engine.io-client:socket flushing 1 packets in socket
engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "pong", data "undefined"
engine.io-client:socket socket close with reason: "transport close"
socket.io-client:manager onclose
socket.io-client:manager cleanup
socket.io-client:socket close (transport close)
socket.io-client:manager will wait 690ms before reconnect attempt
socket.io-client:manager attempting reconnect
```

**Update 3**

I tested with changing Socket.IO path to `/` but didn't work and I got the same result.

**Update 4**

I tested with changing Socket.IO client transport to `polling` but didn't work and I got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. In my case, it was a corrupted JWT secret, and logs also stated this (look at `invalid signature` part). My JWT secret was corrupted due to a [GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/45173#note_291163703).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your connection is closed automatically by nginx. Have you setup WebSocket support in nginx? If not follow the instructions found at this link: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

To verify that this is the problem causing the issue: Try if your application works when the socket.io connection mode is set to polling only.

Comment: I'm using [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) and it seems it handles Nginx configuration correctly as you see in the response of `101 Switching Protocols` I wrote in my question.